# R: How to convert elapsed seconds to time of day based on different start times

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, posixct, datetime-conversion

I want to convert the seconds in "TOTALSEC" to a 24-hr time of day (ie. 14:32:40). However, it needs to be based on the starting time in "Time". So for example, I have "12:00:00" as the start time under Time and "3630" under TOTALSEC". I want to get the converted time to read 13:00:30. For context the Time is start time of an audio recorder, and TOTALSEC is # elapsed seconds that audio clip occurs since the start time. So in the above example, I started the recorded at 12:00:00, and the audio clip occurred 3630 seconds after it started recording.

```
> head(stacksubset)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
TOTALSEC    Time     Date
    <dbl>          <chr>    <chr>
1 10613.67 15:53:50 2017-05-30
2 56404.35 17:29:44 2017-05-29
3 20480.54 16:16:12 2017-06-13
4 60613.47 15:53:50 2017-05-30
5 80034.30 16:16:12 2017-06-02
6 50710.37 16:16:12 2017-05-27
```

I was thinking it might have to be a loop function of some sort (there's 2000 additional lines after the above 6).

Comment: What if the time rolls into the next day?

Comment: 56404 secs is > 15 hours so it will certainly be the case that the time will be the next day for some rows.

Comment: My bad. That is important. I added a Date variable above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Data

```
data <- data.frame(TOTALSEC = c(10613.67, 56404.35, 20480.54, 60613.47, 80034.30, 50710.37),
                   Time = c("15:53:50", "17:29:44", "16:16:12", "15:53:50", "16:16:12", "16:16:12"))
```

---

#### Code

So because date will actually matter here each of the times is pasted to a date (Today's date) and then converted to datetime in the timezone of your system.
Then add together.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate(Time = as_datetime(paste(Date, Time), Sys.timezone(location = TRUE)),
                end_time = TOTALSEC + Time)
```

---

#### Result

```
  TOTALSEC                Time            end_time
1 10613.67 2017-11-23 15:53:50 2017-11-23 18:50:43
2 56404.35 2017-11-23 17:29:44 2017-11-24 09:09:48
3 20480.54 2017-11-23 16:16:12 2017-11-23 21:57:32
4 60613.47 2017-11-23 15:53:50 2017-11-24 08:44:03
5 80034.30 2017-11-23 16:16:12 2017-11-24 14:30:06
6 50710.37 2017-11-23 16:16:12 2017-11-24 06:21:22
```

Comment: Probably safer to just leave it in `tz="UTC"` which `as_datetime` uses by default, as this won't bother with any daylight savings changes etc.

Comment: For non-lubridate users, it is also as simple as - `dat$Time <- as.POSIXct(dat$Time, format="%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC"); dat$EndTime <- dat$Time + dat$TOTALSEC` to use the current date + the timestamp.

Comment: @zacdav how would the code change if the above date information was added? I assume the new column would be a Datetime stamp, which is ideal for me. Thanks

Comment: @mbain its very simple, where the `Sys.Date()` was being pasted with the time, we replace it with the new `Date` column

Comment: @mbain if this worked for you please accept that as the answer :)